# How to refactor an existing project into project libs?

Tags: android, eclipse

We have an original project OP like this:

```
Original Project OP
Class A
Class B 
Class C imports A and B
```

So if we want to take C into a new plib_C, it requires A and B.

The obvious answer is to create a project lib out of A plib_A, another plib_B first.
Then create a new plib_C from C which has in its buildpath the plib_A and plib_B.

But that would imply a very complex and tedious refactoring excercise of about 100+ classes.

So it would be nice just to create

```
New Project NP:
Class A
Class B 
using plib_C in buildpath as a lib
```

and create

```
New Project C:
Class C
using plib_NP in buildpath as a lib
```

I know this is a cycle - that is why this doesn not seem to work unfortunately when I tried that in Eclipse.

Is there a way around this cycle problem except of analyzing all dependencies in OP and createing a purely linear dependency structure without any cycles?

Comment: Wait, are those A, B and C classes, or projects, or..? I'm confused why you have to refactor 100+ classes? If these libraries don't have Android resources (or simply, Java-classes library), you can take those three and build a .jar to be referenced by OP.

Comment: yes they are classes - about 100, with various dependencies like this